# Equipment used for cooking by a non-Jew

Tags: halacha, gentiles, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul

I've heard that even if kosher ingredients and equipment are used, the food cooked (i.e. using heat) by a Gentile isn't kosher in most circumstances. I am wondering what the opinions are regarding whether that also affects the equipment that is used.

This is specifically relevant to me: since I'm not Jewish, can I cook for myself in a kosher kitchen? But I'm not looking for a ruling; I would always ask permission from people regarding their own kitchens :) I just want a clearer idea about what should be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a non-Jew cooks something, the food is rendered non-kosher and **so is the pot it was cooked in** (and spoon it was stirred with, etc.: [*Shulchan Aruch*, *Yore Dea* 113:16](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%92#.D7.98.D7.96)). I'm not sure what the various rulings have been from rabbis over the years, but that is the rule as accepted by Jews (as far as I know in all communities). When I refer to a pot as "non-kosher", I mean that it is considered to have absorbed non-kosher food within its walls and cannot be used to cook food that is meant to be kosher.

However, certain things cooked by non-Jews do not thereby become non-kosher (and, thus, do not render the pot non-kosher). The general rule is that a food often eaten in its uncooked state, or something that (after being cooked) would not be served at a state dinner, does not become non-kosher when cooked by a non-Jew. There are [more details about these and other exceptions](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-bishul.htm) (though, be warned, that page seems to focus exclusively on [Ashkenazic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashkenazi_Jews) practice), but a rabbi should be approached with any questions.

Comment: A great answer, thanks. For any questions she, and even I, would definitely ask a rabbi, but it helps to have a clearer picture. Is there any discussion about the stove or oven being rendered non-kosher, or is it just utensils to be thinking of?

Comment: @Annelise, I've never studied the laws of _bishul akum_ (stuff cooked by a non-Jew) or of _taaruvos_ (mixtures including non-kosher food, including 'mixtures' in the walls of pots and things). So I'm *really* not sure. Based on my study of _basar v'chalav_ (meat with dairy), though, I *suspect* the oven would be rendered non-kosher if a non-Jew cooked something in it that raised steam. Please, please, no one rely on this!

Comment: I'll let you know what I hear :)